# Prevent page jumping on OSX Chrome using bootstrap modal

Tags: javascript, css, macos, twitter-bootstrap

I am using Twitter's Bootstrap 3 modal, and it looks great, except on google chrome (perhaps other broswers too) on OSX, the page underneath jumps left a little bit - probably due to a scrollbar taking some space on the right.

Is there any way to prevent the page jumping when using modal windows on OSX Chrome?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I literally just fixed this problem on my project.

Put this line of code in your css:

```
body.modal-open {
  margin: 0 !important;
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much - you saved me untold pain with this snippet

Comment: no problem! it gave me quite a lot of pain... No idea why they do it

Answer (score 0):

If the above fix doesn't work for any future readers (as it didn't for me), [here's a whole thread](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/9855) detailing potential fixes. Looks like it will be addressed permanently in the next Bootstrap release.